# How can I make it so only a certain role can use a command with discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm attempting to make a command that only works with a certain role. I'm not 100% sure how to do this and I cannot find a solution anywhere else. My code stops short because I'm not very familiar with coding quite yet, but here it is:

```
@bot.command()
async def sign(ctx, member: discordMember):
 if ctx.author.server_roles
```

From here I am completely lost and have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to make it so a command can be used only with a certain role is the `.has_role()` decorator. You may put there a string with the role name (case sensitive) or the role ID (recommended), more info can be found in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.ext.commands.has_role) Here is an example:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Administrator")
async def foo(ctx)
   await ctx.send("bar")
```

If you would like to make it so the user can use this command only when he has any role then `.has_any_role()` would be the way to go, it takes strings or integers as well. You can find more info on it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_any#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role). Here is a quick example on how that would work:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Administrators", "Moderators", 492212595072434186)
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("bar")
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the help! One more thing, how can I make an error message if they don't have the role?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when someone tries to execute such command with a `.has_role` decorator the [discord.ext.commands.MissingRole](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=missing#discord.ext.commands.MissingRole) is raised, so handling it would be something like this :

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Administrators", "Moderators", 492212595072434186)
async def foo(ctx):
    try:
       await ctx.send("bar")
    except commands.MissingRole:
       await ctx.send("lol")
```

Of course if you have a lot of commands, then I would recommend using a global error handler.